# Case sensitive links in spring

Tags: java, spring, debian

I created a porfolio webapp with Spring. Everything worked fine on localhost, so I uploaded a mvn jar on ovh. It's running on Debian 8. I don't know why but my images are *.jpg and *.JPG, and hosted app became case-sensitive. Only the *.jpg images are displayed. I would really appreciate some help. I can't find any solution on my own.

Comment: URL paths are case-sensitive. Maybe you switched from a broken filesystem (NTFS) to one that observes case?

Comment: They are sensitive on Linux but they are not on windows. I found a program that changes files names to lower case. Not the best approach, but the best I got